# Dynamically resizing a GLSurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, resize, draw, glsurfaceview

I'm using a video view extending GLSurfaceView and I want it to be resized when the screen orientation is changing. Typically, to set the view in full screen mode when the screen orientation is landscape.
I'm having trouble to resize this component, setLayoutParams does not do the trick, i also tried the surfaceChanged method of GLSurfaceView without success. I'm probably missing something.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, I think the easiest way would be to utilize Android's default behavior of destroying and recreating your activity containing the `GLSurfaceView` on orientation change.  This would be done by specifying different layouts with the same name for portrait and landscape orientations and placing them in, for example, `res/layout-port` and `res/layout-land` folders.

Another possibility, since `GLSurfaceView` can often contain a lot of state that you may not want to rebuild every time the orientation changes, is to use the [`android:configChanges` attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) in your `Activity` specifying `orientation`, and then resizing your `GLSurfaceView` inside the [`onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) of your `Activity`.